# select between two date fields if not select all

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I made form for searching in my records

the form ask for ID , and stat date , end date

I want if the user dose not select the start and the end dates then Select all records

I try using

```
Between [Forms]![frmCriteria]![Start Date] And [Forms]![frmCriteria]![End Date]
```

but that does not give result if user not pick dates

also

```
 like between Start and End & "*"
```

that one works good if user does not select dates but if he select still it shows all records

Now how to make it work good as I need , * this code is example . I work in MS access and code in criteria build

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
where (date >= Start or Start = "*") and
      (date <= End or End = "*")
```

Actually `"*"` is bad for a date format.  Instead, use the proper types and pass in a `NULL` value:

```
where (date >= Start or Start is null) and
      (date <= End or End is null)
```

Comment: OK but now if Start & End is both set to null how i will select all records regardless the dates

Comment: make it in this form }}Between [Forms]![frmCriteria]![Start Date] And [Forms]![frmCriteria]![End Date]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Between Nz([Forms]![frmCriteria]![Start Date], [YourDateField]) And Nz([Forms]![frmCriteria]![End Date], [YourDateField])
```

where `[YourDateField]` is the field you filter on.

Comment: No at all , cuz it only request dates  if user does not enter date Start & End it will give NOTHING at all

Comment: Then form fields are not Null.